# PHP preg_replace: ignore matches in replaced values

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'd like to replace tokens in a subject with values, using preg_replace.
The tokens in the subject are questionmarks, or named parameters. (Think PDO style)

My current approach works fine, until one of the values contains a question mark itself. (Or a named variable.) In that case the whole system goes bad: the question mark in the replaced value is by itself replaced by the next value.

Basically, I don't want to replace anything that was found in the $values array. So the "recursive" nature of preg_replace is what I'd like to stop.

What's the best way arround that?

Isolated example:

```
<?php

// Values that will be replaced
$values = array (1, 2, 'bla bla ? bla', 'NULL', 4, 'woop woop', 'waap waap');

// Keys used for replacing
$keys = array ('/[?]/', '/[?]/', '/[?]/', '/[?]/', '/[?]/', '/:testvar1/', '/:testvar2/');

// Original text
$original = ":testvar1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, :testvar2";

// Actual replaced text
$actual = preg_replace ($keys, $values, $original, 1);

// Expected replaced text
$expected = "woop woop, 1, 2, bla bla ? bla, NULL, 4, waap waap";

echo '<pre>';
echo "Actual:\n";
echo $actual . "\n\n";
echo "Expected:\n";
echo $expected . "\n\n";
echo "Result:\n";

if ($actual == $expected)
{
    echo '<span style="color: green;">Success!</span>';
}
else
{
    echo '<span style="color: red;">Failure!</span>';   
}
```

Any tips? :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved with lookahead assertions, like so:

```
// Keys used for replacing
$keys = array ('/\?(?=,)/', '/\?(?=,)/', '/\?(?=,)/', '/\?(?=,)/', '/\?(?=,)/');
```

This will make the RE engine match any question mark followed by a comma, *without* making the comma a part of the match. If, however, you ever have replacement values that contain a question mark followed by a comma, you'll encounter this situation again.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it just pushes it back. What if the replacement contains `?,`?

Comment: "If, however, you ever have replacement values that contain a question mark followed by a comma, you'll encounter this situation again."

Comment: So you were aware of the problem... How would you attempt to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace_callback` so you can manually assign replacements, like so:

```
$values = [1,2,'bla bla ? bla','NULL',4];
$original = "?, ?, ?, ?, ?";
$actual = preg_replace_callback("/[?]/",function($m) use (&$values) {
    return array_shift($values);
});
```

Done!

Comment: You're right, that sovles the initial problem. However, the keys must be idential eveyr time then. It probably wasn't very obvious in the question, but the $keys array can be different as well. Will edit original question, sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I've completed the scenario. I've also tried with preg_replace_callback, but with the different order it goes completely mad :)